# move wamp html/css/js to node simple and easy way

Tags: html, node.js

Suppose a html file and associated css/ js/ image/ files exists and is used in wamp.  Can someone tell me a quick way to serve this using node?

Assume index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g pm2
pm2 serve path port
```

The use of PM2 module can be very simple to achieve a static file server.

[enter link description here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/)